# How to design a PyQt/Pyside2 application to use the MVC pattern with the Qt MV pattern?

Tags: mvc, qt

**The context:** I created a PySide2 app to remote control a pyhsical product. The device is interfaced with a driver to get and set it's overall state (state machine with nested and parallel states) and configuration values. Dependend on the overall application state the model requests the product state periodically, means interaction with the model does not happen via the user interface exclusively. To encapsulate the logic I decided to implement the explicit [MVC pattern like described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26698628/mvc-design-with-qt-designer-and-pyqt-pyside/26699122#26699122). To merge the product/application state into the logic I created a `StateMachine` class (actually a `StateChart` class cause it emulates parallel states) and inherited from it in the `Model(QObject, StateMachine)`. A `Controller` class is used to connect the `Model` with the `View` to synchronize the data between the "backend" and the "frontend" like usual with MVC. I decided not to use the Qt specifc [Model/View pattern](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/model-view-programming.html) cause I did not need UI widgets/views which depend on the usage of [`QAbstractItemModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/model-view-programming.html#models) like lists, tables and trees and I do not need several views for the data.

**The problem:** Everything worked perfectly fine until I wanted to add a table with `QTableView` + `QAbstractTableModel`: I created a class `CustomTableModel` inheriting from `QAbstractTableModel`. To merge the data and logic of the table into the overall application data and logic I tried to inject the Qt MV Model `CustomTableModel` into the MVC model `Model(QObject, StateMachine, CustomTableModel)`. Of course this does not work because `CustomTableModel` inherits from `QObject` itself via `QAbstractTableModel`.

**The actual question:** Is it possible to use the Qt MV pattern in combination with the MVC pattern? In case it is: How has it to be done?

Comment: So `Model` inherits from all three `QObject`, `StateMachine`, `CustomTableModel` and the problem is that `CustomTableModel` also inherits from `QObject`? Did you try letting `Model` inherit from only `CustomTableModel` and `StateMachine`?

Comment: I tried `Model(CustomTableModel, StateMachine)` but `Model(QObject, ...)` is passed to `Controller` and `View` class instances which expect `QObject`. For more info refer to the link "MVC pattern like described in this question" above.

Comment: Why not just make your `CustomTableModel` an attribute of the `Model` class? You could do the same for `StateMachine` as well.

Comment: Mh, good point. I'll try it out.